# how to create table same as another table using CTAS and location in hive?

Tags: hive

I write a query:-

```
create external table **table** LOCATION '**hdfs_folder**' as 
select
column1, cloumn2,...
from **another_table**
where
**where_condition**
```

how to do that in hive version Hive 0.12.0-cdh5.1.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `create table like` statement to achieve that, e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_name.table_name
  LIKE existing_table_or_view_name
  LOCATION hdfs_path;
```

[Check out the manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable) for more details